# Photos library not showing in iTunes

Tags: itunes, photos

I can't see any longer any Photos library inside iTunes->Phone->photos.
Nor my full photos collection neither any newly created test library can be chosen in the option "Copy photos from"

I don't know if this issue is related to latest upgrade to macos 10.11.2 or to some old files cleaning I perform recently.

Anyone know what is missing?

Comment: Can Photos.app still find its library correctly?

Comment: Yes, Photos.app is working without problem. I've tried creating a new test library and setting it as system library, but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

If you have moved your library to another folder, like in my case to an external hard drive to save space in my laptop, then you just need to create an alias of the photo library, move it to the Pictures folder, and rename it to "Photos Library"... iTunes will now be able to find it.